# I need to show the footer template under the rows of gridview to insert/add data into this gridview connected with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

Going briefly and to the point,My query is that i have the following code to perform CRUD operation on gridview connected with database in which i have chosen to place columns in template field and i want to place footer template under rows of gridview such that they will allow user to enter or submit data into those footer elements.But the problem is that these footer template never gets created in my gridview.What's problem i Can't find out Please help!

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" EnableViewState="false" />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="AutoId" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" AllowPaging="true"
            PageSize="3" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">

            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnInsert" runat="server"  
               CommandName="Insert">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AutoId" DataField="AutoId" ReadOnly="true" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("FirstNAme") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("LastName") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("Age") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' Columns="3" />

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="REw" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge" Text="*" />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("True") ? "Yes" : "No" %>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />

                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropActive" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Active") %>'>

                            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" />

                            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" />

                        </asp:DropDownList>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtactive" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ForeColor="Red" CommandName="Delete" />

                        </span>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#efefef" />

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />

            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />

            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />

            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ShowFooter="true" to the declaration of your gridview control.